# YouCompleteMe for python default selection

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

YouCompleteMe works quite nicely. But I have a problem with default selection when dot is typed because it selects the first matching. Most of the time it is some name starting with underscore what most of the time is not what I want. For example for string it can select something like "__class__". I have to press the Up arrow key to remove the default selection and start typing. Then it works as expected. But for me it's waste of time to have to press additional button every time I want to use autocompletion.

Anyone's got similar problem?
I have looked through available variables (plugins' configiration) but cannot see anything related to this issue:/

Thank a lot inadvance for help:)

Comment: You don't have to press additional buttons. Just keep typing.

Comment: I can keep typing but it does make sense since something like "\__calss__" appeared. Buceause I would get, for instance: "my string"._class__form -> it does not start to compete it with "format".

Comment: Then something is wrong with your YCM setup. Try their issue tracker.